# Keeping Up with the Joneses, Vocative Edition

Tags: grammaticality, honorifics, category, vocatives, parts-of-speech

**TLDR:** This question is about *vocatives*.  Is there a rule to explain 
how to know whether you can drop a person’s name when addessing someone
just by their title alone, or whether that form is expressly forbidden by some mystery grammar?  I’m looking for some veiled grammatical explanation if there is one.

---

Consider how this group:

- Senator Smith
- Governor Smith
- Minister Smith
- Doctor Smith
- Vicar Smith
- Father Smith
- Sheriff Smith
- Judge Smith
- Nurse Smith
- Professor Smith

Contrasts with this group:

- King Jones
- President Jones
- Pope Jones
- Lord Jones
- Chief Justice Jones
- Speaker Jones

When it comes to how they’re directly addressed, with the Smiths
you can drop the *Smith* part when you address them and it still sounds
alright, albeit somewhat familiar of course:

> - Doctor Smith, the patient will see you now.
> - Doctor, the patient will see you now.

or

> - Senator Smith, your vote today is critical.
> - Senator, your vote today is critical.

But with the Joneses, you can’t seem to get away with that at all:

> - President Smith, the Republic will not long survive such good fortune.
> - *President, the Republic will not long survive such good fortune.
> - Mister President, the Republic will not long survive such good fortune.

or

> - King Smith, the peasants are revolting.
> - *King, the peasants are revolting.
> - Your Majesty, the peasants are revolting.

For whatever reason, the Joneses seem to demand more “little empty words” in direct address than the Smiths do: ***Why is that?***

Some of the Joneses get a *Mister/Madame* like *Mister Chief Justice*
or *Madame Speaker*, while others get fanciful indirect forms from days
of old like *My Lord* or *Your Majesty* or *Your Holiness*,
and all the rest.

In some cases, it feels like you can only drop the name if the remaining
title still applies for you.  So Tommy Smith can call his Uncle Smith just plain
*Uncle*, but it doesn’t feel right for someone who isn’t his uncle to do so;
he’s Tommy’s uncle, not your own.

Why does the grammar differ here?

- What’s the rule for knowing whether can just drop the name and keep the title in *vocative use*?
- Alternately phrased, what’s the rule for knowing whether you have to either add more words like *Mister* if you drop the name?

Are these all actually in the same word-class?

---

#### References consulted

- [English Honorifics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_honorifics) from Wikipedia
- [Manner of Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Style_(manner_of_address)) from Wikipedia
- [Kinship Terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinship_terminology) from Wikipedia
- [Protocol for the Modern Diplomat](http:///www.state.gov/documents/organization/176174.pdf), from the US State Department
- [Debrett’s Courtesy Titles](https://www.debretts.com/expertise/essential-guide-to-the-peerage/courtesy-titles/) from the UK firm

Comment: Might it not just be that "ordinary people" rarely have reason to use words whose primary purpose is to identify and catch the attention of the addressee when they're in the company of kings, presidents, and popes? In days of yore, you could reasonably say [***You there, beggar**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+there+beggar%22), but ***You there, king**!* smacks of *lèse-majesté* to me (and the king probably wouldn't like it too much either! :)

Comment: There's no rule, just arbitrary choices for different honorifics, and you just have to learn them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers without exactly disagreeing with you, your explanation would make more sense if *senator* and *governor* were in the second list.

Comment: @Chris: Brits do actually say, for example, ***Yes, guv! Whatever you say!*** in colloquial contexts, but we don't have much reason to use ***senator, governor*** like that anyway. But I suggest these are much more "lowly" categories, in that each might include many people (whereas there's usually only *one* king, president, or pope in any given context).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you're right, guv'nor. Uniqueness works quite well (but there's always *Lord*).

Comment: I suspect that you add *mister* or *madam* when the title applies to an official or elected position rather than one bestowed by a higher power. Approximately.

Comment: "Vicar Smith" is not a normal way of referring to a person. In the past, the vicar of a Church of England parish might have been addressed as "Vicar" or "Mr. Smith" ("Reverend Smith" is American usage.) Also, in more deferential times Lord Jones would have been addressed as "My lord". NB Kings and popes are known by their given name anyway, so the question doesn't apply .

Comment: English doesn't have formal versus informal second person anymore. The formal seems to have developed as a way to circumlocute around shorter, curt, direct addresses (e.g. development of _ustéd_) and the more respect the personage demanded, the more elaborate the address. Polish has particles (_niech_) just for this purpose.  Some languages still have separate formal versus informal pronouns, but all English has left is the extra verbiage.

Comment: The answer seems blindingly obvious here: **Your title can only be used as a direct vocative if you’re called Smith, not if you’re called Jones.**

Comment: You've written `President Smith` instead of President Jones, and `King Smith` instead of Jones. Since when do we call the monarchy by their surnames? it's always first names: King Arthur, Queen Mary, etc..

Answer (score 1):

There is no grammatical rule, nor generic way of telling. Merely specific references.

I don’t recall *Debrett’s Courtesy Titles* but doubtless, it deals with styles of address such as Lord, Lady or The Hon, usually borne by the sons, daughters, daughters-in-law, brothers, sisters and sisters-in-law of peers, none of which appears in your list - with the possible exception of Lord Jones.

The correct forms for all the people, ranks, titles, styles or what-you-call them are explained in *Debrett’s Correct Form*, by the same publisher, and also in some editions of *Webster’s Dictionary*… (Mine’s in the loft so I can’t check, but it’s a huge one, like a church bible. I think it was printed before Merriam Webster came to be and even today, anyone in an office having anything to do with correspondence should keep one close to hand.)